# Background LED indication in low power mode

Tags: stm32

I'm developing an STM32L4 device which most of its time sleeps in STOP2 mode, wakes up on interrupt, does some job (send data on radio) and sleeps again.

I'd like to add some indication with LEDs, but I don't want this indication to be intrusive. For rare blinks indicating that device is powered on I use LPTIM1 which works great. LED blinks on timer's output pin, device doesn't have to wake up etc. Now I want to blink another LED when interrupt on GPIO pin takes place. I tried to turn led on before doing main job and turn it off right before going to STOP2, but things happen so fast that blinks are barely visible. I want LED to be on for about 100ms. Adding delays isn't what I'd like to do because an interrupt from GPIO or radio may happen and adding some kind of critical sections just for blinking a LED sounds kind of strange.

The best idea I came so far is using analog delay with couple of MOSFETs (simulation tells it should be about 100ms pulse on LED whenever a much shorter pulse comes to diode), but may be there is a way to do it in software? May be there are some best practices of implementing 'background' indication on low power STM32 devices?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTDhRr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Use the 1ms interrupt to light the led. Set a counter for the number of interrupts to light the led (200 for 200ms for example). While the counter is >0 the led in on, each interrupt decrements the the counter.

Comment: @PauloSoares SysTick interrupt isn't available in STOP mode I guess, but probably I shouldn't enter that until indication is complete like so `while(1) { if(some_work) { do_work(); } if (can_sleep) { enter_stop2(); } }`

Comment: Does your microcontroller have more than one pin that the LPTIM output can be multiplexed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LPUART1 is available in STOP2, you can use the TX output to send a pulse. At 32768 Hz clock frequency, you can set it to as low as 90 baud. Transmitting a 0xFF byte would lower the TX output for 9 times the bit time (start bit + 8 data bits). You can either invert the TX output in the `LPUART->CR2` register or connect the LED between TX and V<sub>DD</sub>.

Of course it wouldn't work if you are receiving data on LPUART1 while sleeping, because the baud rate would be wrong.